# Celery - workers not picking up new tasks

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm building a web catalog archiver, using [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html) and [httrack](https://www.httrack.com/) asynchronous mirroring.  I currently have a cluster of three servers, each with five workers per server.  Each task can take between two to six hours to execute.  RabbitMQ is used as the broker, with some backtalk over the rpc channel.

I have the following configuration for each celery server:

```
# Celery init script for ingestion workers
# Set _BIN, _CHDIR, _LOGFILE and _OPTS for the enviroment used.

# This specific configuration is for ingest PROD 2 only
# Define worker nodes to start
CELERYD_NODES="ingest_prod_2_1 ingest_prod_2_2 ingest_prod_2_3 ingest_prod_2_4 ingest_prod_2_5"

# Absolute path to celery executable
CELERY_BIN="/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/proj2.7/bin/celery"

CELERYD_CHDIR="/home/ubuntu/project/proj"

# App instance used
CELERY_APP="ingest.tasks"

#Log file location
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/home/ubuntu/project/logs/django/%N.log"
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="DEBUG"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/home/ubuntu/project/celery_%N.pid"

CELERYD_ACKS_LATE=True
CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER=1

# Celery options, define broker backtalk
CELERYD_OPTS="-b amqp://user:password@host/vhost -Q long_task_queue -c 1 -Ofair"

# Workers should run as an unprivileged user and create dirs if missing
CELERYD_USER="ubuntu"
CELERYD_GROUP="ubuntu"
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1
```

For a stress test exercise, I put in 200 tasks in the task queue.  At first, all workers were active, but soon after all the workers on two servers did not pick up a new task after completing the initial task.  Only one server continued on with all five workers running.  Now, two days later, that one server only has one active worker, all others are idle. As a result, instead of in the neighborhood of ~150 tasks executed, I only see 40.

This is the result of `celery -A ingest.tasks inspect active':

```
-> ingest_prod_3_1@server_1: OK
    - empty -
-> ingest_prod_2_4@server_2: OK
    - empty -
-> ingest_prod_4_3@server_3: OK
    - empty -
-> ingest_prod_3_2@server_1: OK
    - empty -
-> ingest_prod_2_5@server_2: OK
    - empty -
-> ingest_prod_4_5@server_3: OK
    - empty -
-> ingest_prod_3_3@server_1: OK
    - empty -
-> ingest_prod_2_2@server_2: OK
    - empty -
-> ingest_prod_4_1@server_3: OK
    - empty -
-> ingest_prod_3_4@server_1: OK
    - empty -
-> ingest_prod_2_3@server_2: OK
    - empty -
-> ingest_prod_4_2@server_3: OK
    - empty -
-> ingest_prod_3_5@server_1: OK
    * {u'args': u"[u'url', 35637]", u'time_start': 464085.760026547, u'name': u'ingest.tasks.html.download', u'delivery_info': {u'priority': None, u'redelivered': False, u'routing_key': u'backlog.#', u'exchange': u'celery'}, u'hostname': u'ingest_prod_3_5@server_3', u'acknowledged': True, u'kwargs': u'{}', u'id': u'083b575c-8e52-4426-90a5-e9a6ceb117a4', u'worker_pid': 28807}
-> ingest_prod_2_1@server_2: OK
    - empty -
-> ingest_prod_4_4@server_3: OK
    - empty -
```

This is a screenshot of rabbitmq management plugin's queue tab

[image]

The queues I've set up are `backlog` and `ingest`.  All others are set up by rabbitmq.  I'm not sure how to interpret those at this time.

So I'm not sure what's going on here.

Comment: What about rabbit queues ? Tasks are still in the broker or messages have been consumed ? Could be the prefetch your problem http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#std:setting-CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER

Comment: I thought that, so thats why I added `ACKS_LATE=True` and `PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER=1` to the configuration. Seems to have no effect.  Might have to switch to redis as a broker...

Comment: Weird.  I just checked the active workers, and they all are on one machine.  The other two servers in the cluster are idle.

Comment: Hi, I don't think the problem is the broker here. Rabbit MQ is designed to be solid in this and other way more complex scenarios. Can you answer my questions about queue sizes ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by queue sizes, but added a screenshot of the queue tab of rabbitmq management to the question.

Comment: HI, I don't see the queue you mention in your config "long_task_queue" you are using default queue name celery ?
I see that backlog queue with 20 message of which 20 unacked and also the first queue on top.
One question what are you using has RESULT_BACKEND? RabbitMQ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112168/discussion-between-jason-and-mauro-rocco).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After discussion in chat I really think that your problem is having RabbitMQ configured as CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND, this seems clear from the queues having has names UIIDs some of which with high number of messages unconsumed.

This means that tasks are storing results back in the broker but no one is consuming causing RabbitMQ to slow down and freeze.
This was even mentioned in the old docs where it was saing

> Older AMQP backend (badly) emulating a database-based backend.

Use a noSQL or cache system for CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND.

However in the newer versions this messages should expire automatically causing less problem to rabbit MQ as written in the [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html?highlight=CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND#conf-rpc-result-backend).

Comment: Thanks, answer has been changed.